# "Per documentation:" vs. "Per the documentation:"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I often quote the documentation of the software I am writing about on StackOverflow. Typically, I use the short phrase:

> Per documentation:

Also serving as deep link to the quoted passage, followed by the quote.

Recently somebody edited a post of mine to make this:

> Per **the** documentation:

Not the most important detail, but now I wonder which is more correct. I like to be brief, so if either is correct my preference is obvious.

I am typically referring to the *official* documentation of the project, not just *some* documentation, if that should matter.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, saying "Per the documentation" sounds more like a reference to THE documentation, that is OFFICIAL documentation.  Saying, "Per documentation" carries just a hint of "some kind of documentation somewhere."

So I'd recommend "Per the documentation".