# Does the noun after "per" need an article (or other determiner) in the enclosed examples?

Tags: articles

For example, in:

1. There is one property per heading.
2. There is one property per a heading.

The first one seems “more correct”.  Other examples:

- There are two colors per book.
- There are two colors per a book.
- There are two colors per one book.
- There are two colors per each book.

Comment: Addressed in part at [per documentation vs per the documentation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257869/per-documentation-vs-per-the-documentation).